# Cursor to check words

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Engtitle field in sql server table with millions of words.

I want to check how many times each word of table repeats within the table with following condition:

```
select distinct engtitle from table
where a1 = 'EHD'
```

I will get 2million records with above query.and i want to check each word from above query in within same table..with this condition:

Suppose @variable is a one word i get from above query

```
select COUNT(*) from table
where engtitle like '%@variable %'
```

and I want to insert each word with their counts in a table..table2(engtitle,count)

For above condition I tried following cursor:

```
declare @Engword varchar(max)

DECLARE word_cursor CURSOR FOR
select distinct engtitle from table
where a1 = 'EHD'
ORDER BY Engtitle;

OPEN Word_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM Word_cursor
INTO @Engword;
Print @Engword + 'f'

WHILE (select COUNT(*) from table where engtitle like '%@Engword %') > 0  and @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
Print @Engword + 's'

   Insert into Table1(Engtitle,[count])
   Values(@Engword,(select COUNT(*) from table 
where engtitle like '%@Engword %'))

IF (select COUNT(*) from table 
where engtitle like '%@Engword %' ) < 0
Begin
Insert into Table1(Engtitle,[count])
   Values(@Engword,(select COUNT(*) from table 
where engtitle like '%@Engword %'))
END


   FETCH NEXT FROM Word_cursor
   INTO @Engword;
END

CLOSE Word_cursor;
DEALLOCATE Word_cursor;
GO
```

Comment: Getting blank result with above cursor.Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you just want to insert the number of occurances of each word into another table.

I think that should work quite well if you just do a group by select:

```
insert into table1 (
select distinct engtitle, count(0) from table
where a1 = 'EHD'
and engtitle like '@variable'
group by engtitle having count(0) > 0);
```

Comment: yeah but i have a like condition: where engtitle like '%@variable %'

Comment: I want to insert occurance of each word into different condition but i have a like condition for that occurance.

Comment: I edited the answer to also have a like condition in there - that´s assuming you only have one value for the like.
If you have more values on which you want to apply the like condition I think it would have to be a script. Unfortunately I´m rather an oracle guy and not sure of the syntax in sql server, but I think it would work if you have a cursor that gives you the different values for the like condition and execute above statement once for each of those

Comment: Thank you for your help and your effort, but unfortunately it is not helping.